# Using a delegate to pass information from button to highlight cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, mpmediaitem

I have a Parent View Controller and a Child View Controller, and I need to **pass information from a button in the Child View Controller back to the Parent View Controller so that the correct `tableViewCell` text is highlighted.**

In the Parent View Controller when a cell is tapped, the cell text is highlighted, and the Child View Controller pops on screen and plays the song that was selected.  However, on the Child View Controller there is a skip backward and skip forward button, so when either of those is pressed and the Parent View Controller is shown again the **cell text needs to be highlighted for a different cell now than was highlighted before**.

So I've added the proper delegate boilerplate code to each view controller, but I'm not sure the best information to grab from the Child View Controller to send back to the Parent View Controller, and how to use that.

**Child View Controller**:

```
-(IBAction)indexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Blip_Select" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];

    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            [click play];
            [click play];
            [musicPlayer skipToPreviousItem];
            break;
        case 1:
            [click play];
            if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
                [musicPlayer pause];
            } else {
                [musicPlayer play];
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            [click play];
            [click play];
            [musicPlayer skipToNextItem];
        default:
            break; 
    } 
}
```

I would add something inside of each of the above switch statements, but **I'm not sure what exactly would work best**?

Because this is what it looks like in the **Parent View Controller**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AlbumsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MPMediaItem *rowItemAlbum = [[albumsArrayForTVC objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] representativeItem];
    NSString *albumDetailTitle = [rowItemAlbum valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    MPMediaQuery *albumMPMediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: albumDetailTitle forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [albumMPMediaQuery addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
    NSArray *albumTracksArray = [albumMPMediaQuery items];

    MPMediaItem *rowItemSong = [[albumTracksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];
    NSString *songTitle = [rowItemSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.textLabel.text = songTitle;
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    return cell;
}
```

I know I'd add some sort of method, and reload the table, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: implement delegate on your child VC, then work with the datasource on the parent VC, then reload the table, like set an Int to decide which row is highlighted

Comment: Try to use the Block as a callback in the children view controller. And define what the block do in the parent view controller.

Comment: @Tj3n that all makes sense and was along the lines of what I was thinking too, but wasn't sure how to do the Int part that you're talking about, like how exactly to implement a +1/-1 in the parent VC ya know?

Comment: @EricXuan what Block are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a protocol in your child controller.   This protocol should have a method like 'didSelectSkipButton' that accepts some parameter to represent the type of button pressed.
2. Define a delegate property for your child view controller, conforming to the protocol.
3. In the child's indexChanged, send the didSelectSkipButton message to the delegate, passing the value representing the pressed button.
4. In your parent vc, set itself up as the child's delegate and implement the protocol methods.   In `didSelectSkipButton`, find the table view's current row using `indexPathForSelectedRow` and add or subtract one from `[indexpath row]` depending on the button pressed.  Check that the new row index is within the valid bounds for your table view.   Then send your table view a 
   `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` message to select the new row.

Comment: Thanks for the response! #3 + #4 is the sort of thing I didn't have yet and was trying to figure out how to solve.  Let me try to cook up a solution with this.

Comment: In #4, I've got "find the table view's current row using indexPathForSelectedRow" `NSIndexPath *indexPathSelected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` and Check that the new row index is within the valid bounds for your table view. Then send your table view a selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: message to select the new row."  `if(indexPath < albumTracksArrayForTVC.count){
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathSelected animated:YES scrollPosition:
     UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }`.

Comment: But I'm missing "and add or subtract one from [indexpath row] depending on the button pressed." in between the two.  Do you know what I should do there?

Comment: I've got the -/+ from the child with '[_delegate didSelectSkipButton:-1];' for skip back and `[_delegate didSelectSkipButton:+1];` for skip forward.

Comment: And also,the text needs to be highlighted for a different cell now than was highlighted before, but now no cells text is highlighted?

Comment: "add or subtract": so,you've got the current index path with indexPathSelected, then currentRow = [indexPathSelected row].   NSIndexPath *newRow = currentRow + <the value of the button pressed (+1 or -1)>.   You then do if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < [tableView count]) selectRowAtIndexPath....   Sorry, I would give you sample code, but I'm on the road.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for responding, I think I've got it worked out now with the help of your last comment!

Answer (score 2):

Create delegate in your child view controller

```
 @protocol ChildView_Delegate <NSObject>
 -(void)reSelectTableRow:(int)index
 @end
```

create a property in your child view controller

```
@property (nonatomic) id delegate;
```

And when you press forward & backward button do something like this.

```
-(IBAction)forward:(id)sender{
   if(_delegate){
      [_delegate reSelectTableRow:position+1];
   }
}
```

Back in your main controller implement ChildView_Delegate & implement it's method like this

```
 -(void)reSelectTableRow:(int)index{
   if(index<songsArray.count){
     //define a index path
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index  inSection:0];
     //select a row of table view programatically
     [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:
     UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I was thinking it would need to be some sort of +1/-1 solution, but not sure how to implement that back on the main controller

Comment: (Going to try to implement!)

Comment: I think I've got this except the text needs to be highlighted for a different cell now than was highlighted before, but now no cells text is highlighted?

Comment: Also I'm not sure `inSection:` should be `0` right?  Or should that always be `0`?

Comment: section is about for which section row you want to heighlight

Comment: Ah I see what your saying

Answer (score 1):

Add delegate method in parent

```
 @protocol childDelegate <NSObject>
 -(void) updateTable
 @end
```

and

```
@property (assign) id <childDelegate> cDelegate;
```

Then add same method in parent

```
-(void) updateTable
{
  [yourTableView reloadData];
}

-(IBAction)indexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
  [self.cDelegate updateTable];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I already have all of the boilerplate delegate code, but wasn't sure how to implement a method to +1/-1 to the Parent, you know? Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: And more importantly, text needs to be highlighted for a different cell now than was highlighted before, do you know how to do that?